# Findelement "Run-time error '32' "Compound Class names not permitted"

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I am trying to automatically run a program to compare mortgage insurance from various companies.

I need to hit a "Submit" button to get the mortgage insurance amounts. The program I use stalls at this screen, instead of "auto-clicking" to the next screen.

This is what the code looks like:

```html
<button class="full-width ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" pbutton="" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">Order Quotes</span></button>
<span class="ui-button-text ui-clickable">Order Quotes</span>
```

The part that says `<span class>` I know is the key to this.  But the area above it also has something to do with it because when I hover over the button, there are two ways the button is "emphasized". The top codes darkens the whole button.  Whereas the bottom code only highlights the wording inside the button.

I tried the following code(s)

```
Driver.FindElementsByClass("ui-button-text ui-clickable").Click
```

I get

> Run-time error '32' "Compound Class names not permitted"

```py
Driver.FindElementsByClass("full-width ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only").Click
```

I get the same "Run-time error '32'" message as above.

I have other items in this program with a `.click` after the line and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Run-time error '32' message saying "Compound Class names not permitted` the error suggested that `FindElementsByClass()` doesn't support multiple class names
it supports only `class name`

You can either pass single class only in `FindElementsByClass()` or use `FindElementByCss()` or `FindElementByXPath()`

Option 1:

```
 Driver.FindElementsByClass("ui-button-text").Click
```

Option 2:

```
 Driver.FindElementByCss(".ui-button-text.ui-clickable").Click
```

Option 3:

```
Driver.FindElementByXPath("//span[text()='Order Quotes']").Click
```

Comment: KunduK - It appears to be working. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: @DavidfromMke I just noticed you did another question, and you stated this one got solved, would you kindly accept Kunduk as such? Click the checkmark on the answer: doing so helps other users to know this is the answer that solved your problem and encourages other members to know that you're commited to accept answers :)

Comment: SG - sorry about that. Still figuring this site.  Thanks for the headsup. Will try and be more careful.